# Delphi - merge images to new single file and read data

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for some kind of solution in order to be able to merge several images into one single file, and then read/show these images one by one back from that file;

An example of the idea how it could be:

Images (jpeg, but it would be nice to support other formats as well. This principle might be used to basically merge any file type to the final file) are converted to hex or binary data, at the beginning (or both, beginning and the end) there would be some header (header/footer) information, such as let's say file type, extension, name, and maybe even date (although these infos are already in the file itself, but I'd like to have that in header as well, because of -->   ) along with some anchor, so that when reading the new merged file I could identify the file start/end, and so know which part to either extract to some temp location (or preferred - memory), or directly just show as the file type it originally was.

It doesn't need any special encryption, for every file, as it's not some extra supersafe thing, it's just about having all in one file + exe to read/write that file.

Is that in some way achievable as I imagined or not?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The file would still preferable need to have some basic secirity. Meaning, if its new filetype created, with custom separators, thats fine, with zip/rar, I'd use password protection at least... not unbreakable, but still safe to ordinary users...

Comment: You can use the zip format. Delphi comes with zip classes.

Comment: Alternatively, [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may suit your requirements.

Comment: How will these files be accessed at a later date?

Comment: @David Heffernan Zip wouldn't be useful. I still prefer not to be able to have the file opened using WinRar or similar tools that easy...

Comment: @J... I believe that structured storage works in some way just as zip format, only with no compressing engine, right?  As said, I'd still prefer to have at least some basic security, not opened by just any program...

Comment: @Graymatter by the same app, as suggested - preferably with loading the whole file into memory at runtime, and then access parts of it by identifying the start and end of the original file's content.

Comment: Will you be adding new files to the storage or modifying files in the storage?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan although, if I could use some sort of zip/rar format with password set, that would be kind of enough safe for what I need actually... Will take a look on this one.

But, how hard is it actually to create sort of my own file format, in some similar way as I described in the question..? Is it too much work not worth it or could it be done some mid-easy way..?

Comment: It's no good adding requirements after the fact. How could you fail to mention that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fail to mention the fact I would like some basic security..?  Well, I thought that seeking for the custom file creation does make a fact here, that ordinary zip is not the main idea.. :/

Comment: Please don't make us guess. Please edit question to make requirements clear.

Comment: @JustMarc Why would you want to release yet another proprietary, closed format on the world?

Comment: Well, I'm not planning to release it to the world anyway...  quite limited usage area, but as such, I want to make it portable (2 files, exe + data) and with some basic auth...
More than anything, I'm just exploring the options and procedures to achieve that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this before... why not just use SQLite? There's a free Google-written encryption option for it, you can use BLOBs to store all of your images, you can have as many additional fields or even tables as you need to store metadata, there's no additional dependencies, it's small, cross-platform and single-file, etc.

The SQLite website touts the advantages of using SQLite for an application file format:

1. Simplified Application Development
2. Single-File Documents
3. High-Level Query Language
4. Accessible Content
5. Cross-Platform
6. Atomic Transactions
7. Incremental And Continuous Updates
8. Easily Extensible
9. Performance
10. Concurrent Use By Multiple Processes
11. Multiple Programming Languages
12. Better Applications

http://sqlite.org/appfileformat.html

I believe SQLite meets your needs better than any other solution, including being the easiest to implement by far.

And on a personal note... please, please, please think twice, and then two more times after that, before unleashing another proprietary, undocumented, custom file format on the world. And then think again, and then look at pictures of Linus Torvalds and Richard Stallman before deciding. :-) Everyone who's been programming long enough or just using computers long enough has a horror story (or several) about having data stuck in a file format they can't extract it from. Always prefer open, well-documented solutions. It'll make your life and others' much easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I actually never thought about database usage on this one. But you're right!

As already said about the new file being made - it's not to be released to the world anyway! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options available to you:

1) TIF - TIF is a multiple image format. You could embed a number of images in a single TIF file. You obviously wouldn't be able to embed another multi-image file inside of a TIF file. For example another TIF file. You can find more information on TIF files here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format).

2) Compression file - 7-zip / zip / etc - There are multiple libraries, both free and open source, to work with compressed files, for example: https://code.google.com/p/d7zip/. You can also use the zlib library that comes with Delphi but that will need some tweaking.

3) Solid File solution - The one I know of is the Eldos one but I am sure there are others (https://www.eldos.com/solfs/). This is a component or library that "tricks" your application into working with a single file. The application thinks that it's working with a normal file system.

4) Structured Storage - Courtesy of J - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

5) You own file format - Design your own file structure that will give you what you need. This depends on whether the files will be updated after adding them or not. Something as simple as this should work if the data is not changing:

- Length of file name - 2 bytes
- File Name - Specified by length above
- Size of file - 4 bytes
- Next file location - 4 bytes (0 indicates last file in sequence)
- File data - Specified by length above

This block would just repeat for each file with the last file having a 0 as the next file location.

Some code for the last option (without encryption) would look like this:

```
procedure ReadCustomFile(const aPackageFile: string);
var
  filename: string;
  loadData: TFileStream;
  filenameLength: Word;
  imageDataLength: Integer;
  imageNext: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  imageStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  loadData := TFileStream.Create(aPackageFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    repeat
      imageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        loadData.Read(filenameLength, SizeOf(filenameLength));
        SetLength(filename, filenameLength);
        loadData.Read(filename[1], filenameLength);
        loadData.Read(imageDataLength, SizeOf(imageDataLength));
        loadData.Read(imageNext, SizeOf(imageNext));
        imageStream.CopyFrom(loadData, imageDataLength);
        imageStream.SaveToFile('a'+filename);
      finally
        imageStream.Free;
      end;
    until imageNext = 0;
  finally
    loadData.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure WriteCustomFile(const aPackageFile: string; const aImageFileList: array of string);
var
  filename: string;
  loadData: TFileStream;
  filenameLength: Word;
  imageDataLength: Integer;
  imageNext: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  imageStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  loadData := TFileStream.Create(aPackageFile, fmCreate or fmExclusive);
  try
    for I := Low(aImageFileList) to High(aImageFileList) do
    begin
      filename := aImageFileList[I];
      imageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        imageStream.LoadFromFile(filename);
        filenameLength := Length(filename);
        loadData.Write(filenameLength, SizeOf(filenameLength));
        loadData.Write(filename[1], filenameLength);
        imageDataLength := imageStream.Size;
        loadData.Write(imageDataLength, SizeOf(imageDataLength));
        if I = High(aImageFileList) then
          imageNext := 0
        else
          imageNext := loadData.Position + imageStream.Size + SizeOf(imageNext);
        loadData.Write(imageNext, SizeOf(imageNext));
        loadData.CopyFrom(imageStream, imageStream.Size);
      finally
        imageStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    loadData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This code would be called like this:

```
WriteCustomFile('ConsolidatedFile.pkg', ['Test1.bmp','Test2.bmp']);
ReadCustomFile('ConsolidatedFile.pkg');
```

It's pretty rough but it should give you an idea of what to do. Adding an deleting would complicate things because you will need to copy the stream and insert the blocks in that you need. Adding less so because it would just be one pointer that needs to change. Depending on how big this file is likely to get, it might just be easier to create a new one each time you want to change it.

Comment: #5 means basically to reinvent #2, badly. It's just a lot of work for no discernible benefit.

Comment: @mghie Not necessarily. Companies do it all of the time. It depends what the OP wants to do. Images are already compressed so there are almost no benefits to push them through a compression engine. A home backed solution would be faster depending on how its implemented. It would just be less flexible. If the OP wanted to change some of the files than a compression library falls back further as they are not really built for files that continuously change. But a home backed solution becomes much more complex in that case.

Comment: Any one-off solution would have to have major benefits over an existing library to offset the effort spent to write it.

Comment: @mghie Performance is one reason. Regardless, the point is that it is a valid option.

Comment: @Graymatter thanks for the suggestions.
The first one wouldn't go for me, as I intend to be able to use some other formats as well; 
The 2nd might be good, as I already commented in the question's comments, if it could be use with some password, but would still prefer not to use compressing engine....
3) is that possible to protect in any way, or is it like some kind of ISO like file..?
4) isn't that quite similar to number 3...? Like having some VHD mounted within the app? Sort of the way as VMWare and VirtualPC has it's disks..? Am I wrong on this one?

Comment: 5) would suit me the best. Not so much in any other perspective but the one that I could use some new knowledge about file handling etc... :)
Any good tips on doing this one? How much of work is actually to do something like my own file format in such way?

Comment: @JustMarc The difference between 3 and 4 is one is a custom library and the second is baked into the OS. The eldos solution does encrypt data, I am not sure about other similar libraries. The work required for a custom solution depends on whether the app will change the files and how you will be adding files.

Comment: @Graymatter the files won't be changed. The main file however would be. the add and delete functions would be useful. But direct changes to the images/files itself wont be made. So basically deleting from start to end point of some file would be made, and adding, too (to the end of the file, the simplest way I believe..? )